# Given a virtual raster .VRT-file and a coordinate (E,N), how does one get the filename of GeoTIFF source, which contains the given coordinate?

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, coordinates

I'm new to GDAL and to GIS related Python packages in general with background more on data science libraries (such as Scikit-learn). The GIS related terminology is also a bit new to me which makes it a bit challenging to read GDAL-related documentations. Because I did not manage to find a solution with some moments of Googling or reading the GDAL manual, so I ask my question here.

My problem is very simple:

Given a virtual raster .VRT-file and some coordinate (E,N), how does one get the filename of the GeoTiff-source, which containts the given coordinate? Does there exists a function for this in GDAL?

As I've understood, .vrt-file is basically a virtual mosaic representation (stitched into one big GeoTIFF naming) of a multiple smaller GeoTiff-files (called tiles). If in Python my .vrt-file is denoted as `vrt_file`, then is there some function in GDAL, which allows me to give it a coordinate (E,N) and the `vrt_file` as input, and the function then returns the filename and/or path to the GeoTIFF, which "contains this coordinate inside its geographical  coordinate borders"?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you can just query the point directly in the VRT- could you describe what you are trying to do as well as what you have tried so far.

Comment: Dear @IanTurton thank you for your comment. Sorry I don't fully understand your question. Does my post not explain what I'm trying to do? How does one make this query? Or do you need a more detailed question? What I've done is this: "I've been looking for a function from GDAL documentation, which achieves what I'm trying to do". I could program this manually myself, but this approach is not optimal, since I suspect GDAL would have functionality for this, or does it?

Comment: To add on previous, my question is analogous with this one: "Does OpenCV contain a way to access webcam data?" Answer: "Yes, you can use the VideoCapture-object for this"

Comment: VRT is virtual mosaic and it is not restricted to GeoTIFFs as input. And the result is not GeoTIFF but more abstract, a GDAL dataset that can be materialized into some file format. And yes, knowing that VRT can be used as it can, there must be methods for finding the right source files. Perhaps it happens here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/frmts/vrt/vrtdataset.cpp.

Comment: I believe that GDAL is more abstract. GDAL user needs to get pixels from a layer (from any layer, VRT, GeoTIFF, whatever) and uses ReadBlock for that https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Band-class.html#ReadBlock. It is a job for the VRT driver to find the correct files and select correct pixels for the output. There is not necessarily a need to report what those files are for the user and I do not find a method for that from the Python API https://gdal.org/python/index.html.

Comment: For your needs I would perhaps convert the raster boundaries into polygons with gdaltindex or some other method and make the point-in-polygon query with GDAL OGR vector methods.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for your help, pity. I would have simply used this information to validate my other code, which uses gdal. P.S. if you give a link to some example, where your solution is applied I'd be very grateful :) But this also helps.

Comment: You may get the names of the files if you keep the VRT but move or rename the source files. Then try to read some data around your point of interest and see if you happen to get the name of the missing file. If that happens then as a programmer you certainly can find out where it comes.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you, very good. Yes, I indeed can you do it no problem. I just wanted to find out if I can find such a ready-made function with relative ease without instead of going into the source code-level, following the call hierarchies, find out what the uncommented code does line by line, editing the source code for my needs --> not worth the time. Faster to just make a script from scratch by myself. It is a bit surprising though, for a newbie on this library, that such a function does not exist in the API.

Comment: If the task is to find the image at a given point without programming I would create a shapefile with gdaltindex and make a query with ogrinfo, pseudocommand `ogrinfo -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from tileindex where ST_Intersects(geometry, my_reference_point)" tileindex.shp`. Gdaltindex and VRT both construct just envelopes of the rasters so the result should be accurate. With not too much work the same could be done with Python.

Comment: Gdal developers can be connected through the gdal-dev mailing list, I suggest to write mail and ask.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for your help! I made the function myself and even though a bit clumsy, gets the job done in my application.

Comment: `gdallocationinfo` does this: https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html#cmdoption-gdallocationinfo-lifonly  You could call that from Python, or perhaps reimplement the same logic: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp#L380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself by making the following trivial script function, because I did not find a similar (and more elegant and general) from GDAL.

You give as input a coordinate of interest and a list of GeoTiff-paths which constitute the .vrt-file.

```
def get_geotiff_filepaths_which_contain_xy_coords(x_coord, y_coord, list_of_vrt_geotiff_filepaths):
   list_of_geotiffs_that_contain_coord_xy = []
   for input_tiff_path in list_of_vrt_geotiff_filepaths:
       tiff_data = gdal.Open(input_tiff_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly) 
       geotransform = tiff_data.GetGeoTransform()
       # Get GeoTiff borders
       minx = geotransform[0] 
       maxy = geotransform[3] 
       pix_x = geotransform[1]
       pix_y = geotransform[5]
       x_ext = tiff_data.RasterXSize
       y_ext = tiff_data.RasterYSize 
       maxx = minx + pix_x * x_ext
       miny = maxy + pix_y * y_ext
       # Check if coordinate is inside geotiff borders
       if ((minx <= x_coord) and (x_coord <= maxx) and (miny <= y_coord) and (y_coord <= maxy)):
          list_of_geotiffs_that_contain_coord_xy.append(input_tiff_path)
   return list_of_geotiffs_that_contain_coord_xy
```

Comment: P.S. I'm using ETRS-TM35FIN as my coordinate system --> to my understanding, makes a planar projection of the coordinates, you can use euclidean distance to measure distance between two points. That's why I can calculate the miny and maxx in the simple way in my function.

Comment: Nice code contribution, and easy to connect EPSG:3067 to your username. When you meet first images that has much nodata you must improve your method and generate accurate polygons for the data area if it is importand if VRT finds not only a file but also data from a point.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for the addition :) Indeed, this was just a quick-and-dirty solution ;)